# count occurrence of a list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, count

Python

I have a list of lists. like

```
A = [[x,y],[a,b],[c,f],[e,f],[a,b],[x,y]]
```

I want to count how many times each list occurred in the main list.

My output should be like

```
[x,y] = 2
[a,b] = 2
[c,f] = 1 
[e,f] = 1
```

Comment: Convert lists to tuples. Use `collections.Counter` on it

Comment: Depends on what `x`, `y`, `a`, etc are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
from collections import Counter
A = [[x,y],[a,b],[c,f],[e,f],[a,b],[x,y]]

new_A = map(tuple, A) #must convert to tuple because list is an unhashable type

final_count = Counter(new_A)


#final output:

for i in set(A):
   print i, "=", final_count(tuple(i))
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) - a dict subclass - to take the counts. First, convert the sublists to tuples to make them usable (i.e. hashable) as dictionary keys, then count:

```
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(map(tuple, A))
```

Comment: Doesn't work with for example `x = y = a = b = c = d = e = f = []`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use pandas for cleaner code:

```
pd.Series(A).explode().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your output, you can `loop` through a `set` of your `list` and print each item with its `count()` from the original `list`:

```
for x in set(map(tuple, A)):
    print '{} = {}'.format(x, A.count(list(x)))
```

Comment: This won't work for lists (but it will for tuples, see other answers).