# i want to get count for each tuple occurring together

Tags: python, list

I'm new top python and want your support to do following operation. I have list of lists as below:

```
item = [[8, 28], [8, 33], [8, 38], [8, 43], [13, 18], [13, 23],
        [13, 28], [13, 33], [13, 38], [13, 43], [18, 23], [18, 28],
        [18, 33], [18, 38], [18, 43], [23, 28], [23, 33], [23, 38],
        [23, 43], [28, 33], [28, 38], [28, 43], [33, 38], [33, 43],
        [38, 43], [4, 9], [4, 14], [4, 19], [4, 24], [4, 29], [4, 34],
        [4, 39], [4, 44], [9, 14], [9, 19], [9, 24], [9, 29], [25, 30],
        [25, 35], [25, 40], [25, 45], [30, 35], [30, 40], [30, 45]]
```

I want to get the count for each tuple occurring together, I tried to apply this code:

```
collection.Counter(item)
```

The following error occured:

```
count_elements(self, iterable)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: What you have is list of lists, not a list of tuples. List are mutable and therefore unhashable which is why you get the error. Where are you getting the list from?  If you could get it in the form `[(8, 28), (8, 33), (8, 38),...] `you might have better luck

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019607/count-occurrence-of-a-list-in-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminarily, square brackets indicate a list, while parentheses indicate a tuple. Thus, `item` is a list of lists, not a list of tuples. A list of tuples would look more like [(8, 28), (8, 33), (8, 38), (8, 43)...] An easy way to convert `item` to a list of tuples is to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple):

```
fixed_item = map(tuple, item)
```

That said: If what you want to do is simply count the number of tuples within `item`, that's just the length of the list, so you can use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
len(fixed_item)
```

If what you want to do is count how many times each individual tuple is repeated within `item`, that's where [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) can be useful.

```
from collections import Counter
new_counter = Counter(fixed_item)
```

`new_counter` will then contain a dictionary in which each tuple in `item` is a key, and the corresponding value is how many times that particular tuple appears in `item`.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to make a list of tuples, as your question suggests, you can convert all the inner brackets to parentheses, like so:

```
items = [(8, 28), (8, 33), (8, 38), (8, 43), (13, 18), (13, 23), (13, 28), (13, 33), (13, 38), (13, 43), (18, 23), (18, 28), (18, 33), (18, 38), (18, 43), (23, 28), (23, 33), (23, 38), (23, 43), (28, 33), (28, 38), (28, 43), (33, 38), (33, 43), (38, 43), (4, 9), (4, 14), (4, 19), (4, 24), (4, 29), (4, 34), (4, 39), (4, 44), (9, 14), (9, 19), (9, 24), (9, 29), (25, 30), (25, 35), (25, 40), (25, 45), (30, 35), (30, 40), (30, 45), (35, 40), (35, 45), (40, 45), (1, 6), (1, 11), (1, 16), (1, 21), (1, 26), (1, 31), (1, 36), (1, 41), (1, 46), (6, 11), (6, 16), (6, 21), (6, 26), (6, 31), (6, 36), (6, 41), (6, 46), (11, 16), (11, 21), (11, 26), (11, 31), (11, 36), (11, 41), (11, 46), (16, 21), (16, 26), (16, 31), (16, 36), (16, 41), (16, 46), (21, 26), (21, 31), (21, 36), (21, 41), (21, 46), (26, 31), (26, 36), (26, 41), (26, 46), (31, 36), (31, 41), (31, 46), (36, 41), (36, 46), (41, 46), (2, 7), (2, 12), (2, 17), (2, 22), (2, 27), (2, 32), (2, 37), (2, 42), (2, 47), (7, 12), (7, 17), (7, 22), (7, 27), (7, 32), (7, 37), (7, 42), (7, 47), (12, 17), (12, 22), (12, 27), (12, 32), (12, 37), (12, 42), (12, 47), (17, 22), (17, 27), (17, 32), (17, 37), (17, 42), (17, 47), (22, 27), (22, 32), (22, 37), (22, 42),(22, 47),(27, 32)]
```

This is because `[]` denotes a list, and `()` denotes a tuple in python. If you do this, then Counter would definitely start working.

However, if what you want is a list of lists and comparing them, Counter may not work as you want. You can convert each element to a tuple programmatically with:

`item_tuples = [tuple(item) for item in items]`

and then using that list of tuples in your counter.

Answer (score 0):

Your sublists (the pairs of numbers) can not be used as `dict` keys because they are not hashable (because lists are mutable).

To solve you can change your lists to tuples

```
item_list = [
    (8, 28), (8, 33), (8, 38), (8, 43), (13, 18), (13, 23),
    (13, 28), (13, 33), (13, 38), (13, 43), (18, 23), (18, 28),
    (18, 33), (18, 38), (18, 43), (23, 28), (23, 33), (23, 38),
    (23, 43), (28, 33), (28, 38), (28, 43), (33, 38), (33, 43),
    (38, 43), (4, 9), (4, 14), (4, 19), (4, 24), (4, 29), (4, 34),
    (4, 39), (4, 44), (9, 14), (9, 19), (9, 24), (9, 29), (25, 30),
    (25, 35), (25, 40), (25, 45), (30, 35), (30, 40), (30, 45),
]
c = collections.Counter(item_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of lists you can convert the lists into tuples and then `collection.Counter(item)` will work:

```
from collections import Counter

item_lists = [[8, 28], [8, 33], [8, 38], [8, 43], [13, 18], [13, 23], [13, 28],
              [13, 33], [13, 38], [13, 43], [18, 23], [18, 28], [18, 33],
              [18, 38], [18, 43], [23, 28], [23, 33], [23, 38], [23, 43],
              [28, 33], [28, 38], [28, 43], [33, 38], [33, 43], [38, 43],
              [4, 9], [4, 14], [4, 19], [4, 24], [4, 29], [4, 34], [4, 39],
              [4, 44], [9, 14], [9, 19], [9, 24], [9, 29], [25, 30], [25, 35],
              [25, 40], [25, 45], [30, 35], [30, 40], [30, 45]]

item_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in item_lists]
print(Counter(item_tuples))
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({(8, 28): 1, (8, 33): 1, (8, 38): 1, (8, 43): 1, (13, 18): 1, (13, 23): 1, (13, 28): 1, (13, 33): 1, (13, 38): 1, (13, 43): 1, (18, 23): 1, (18, 28): 1, (18, 33): 1, (18, 38): 1, (18, 43): 1,(23, 28): 1, (23, 33): 1, (23, 38): 1, (23, 43): 1, (28, 33): 1, (28, 38): 1, (28, 43): 1, (33, 38): 1, (33, 43): 1, (38, 43): 1, (4, 9): 1, (4, 14):1, (4, 19): 1, (4, 24): 1, (4, 29): 1, (4, 34): 1, (4, 39): 1, (4, 44): 1, (9, 14): 1, (9, 19): 1, (9, 24): 1, (9, 29): 1, (25, 30): 1, (25, 35): 1, (25, 40): 1, (25, 45): 1, (30, 35): 1, (30, 40): 1, (30, 45): 1})
```

*Note: It looks like all of your items only exist once in your original list, at the moment.*