# Counter for nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a list x like this `[8, 8, 8]` this works fine:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(x)
```

For a list x like this though `[[6, 88], [35, 64], [15, 7]]` the above does not work.

I am not interested in counting via sFrames, panda etc. Can this be done for such a list similarly, or do I have to make a new correctly concatenated value in the list so as to count?

I am not interested in the count of 6, 88, 35,... rather the count of [6,88], [35, 64]...

So the expected output should be:

```
Counter({[6,88]: 3}, ...)
```

if at all possible.

Comment: What answer do you expect from that array?

Comment: @usr2564301 I am not interested in the count of 6, 88, 35,... rather the count of [6,88], [35, 64]...

Comment: I find it somewhat arrogant the closure here as the pointed to answers do not actually provide the answer. I am not an idiot.

Comment: That output is not possible, as those lists can't be keys. `Counter(map(tuple, x))`?

Comment: @johnsharpe So sir. Thx. I suggest the question be reopened and that answer be provided. Now I know that and can convert to dataframe and check.

Comment: That just changes what it's a dupe of, which I've done.

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK, but the central point here is the quick down voting on this site. Anyway thx.

Comment: @jonrsharpe   Nice try but I can't use a tuple.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. Your question was unclear, at least three people (two voters to close and one answerer) interpreted it as being about flattening, and doesn't show any research effort. And *why* can't you use a tuple? What's the *context* for this? Any other secret constraints?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Pls, no research effort? If you look at what I have done in the past and a bounty, I find that pretty hard to swallow. I am doing the travelling salesman problem with 10 lines of python and am checking the provided solution painstakingly statement by statement and pure python is a little new. This embodies the issues on SO, aside to the good things. I also provided Counter as a n example.

Comment: I'm not saying you've made no effort, I can't know that, I'm saying this question doesn't *show* any. Given the error from the Counter you could have looked up the current dupe as well as I did, for example.

Comment: How about `cnt = [l.count(i) for i in l]`? You can still do something like `cnt[l.index([6, 88])]` to get the count.

Comment: @Chris  I will look at that.

Comment: @Chris   interesting insight, thx, partial solution as I would need to reduce or get distincts. That I think would do the trick. Thx

Comment: You don't need to change your original data, you can just do: `Counter(tuple(sub) for sub in lst)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe   I see answer in the comments not mentioned by the duplicates. Pls consider re-opening.

Comment: Can you just explain your remark about not being able to use tuples?

Comment: My ignorance and it was someone else's code example that I was evaluating, learning from. travelling salesman algorithm in 10 lines.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and here is the correct dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019607/count-occurrence-of-a-list-in-a-list-of-lists ....

Comment: But I can now , thx anyway.

Comment: @thebluephantom BTW, I just noticed that this is actually the same as jonrsharpe's comment from half an hour ago: `Counter(map(tuple, x))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo  I missed it then, but am happy I know the answer.

Comment: Please don't put answers in the question. The dupe about counting lists in lists is a more specific application of the same solution from the dupe about lists being unhashable (i.e. tuples, which apparently you *can* use after all); if one is relevant, both are. I've removed the third, which again means the below (accepted!) answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score -1):

Multi-dimensional lists can be flattened with list comprehension, so you could try:

```py
c = Counter([i for sublist in x for i in sublist])
```

Comment: @thebluephantom why have you accepted this if it isn't the answer to your question? Either the first dupe you complained about was correct, or this answer is wrong.

Comment: As I can use the answer as a work-around.

Comment: The question is not about flattening... Check the expected output